# Get HTML after Javascript execution/modification with WKWebView and Regex in Swift 4+

Tags: javascript, swift, regex

I have been trying to retrieve some data from a website which seems like javascript performs a modification before/after load

I want to find a specific DIV into HTML, and it just doesn't appear to be there the way I'm doing this, it loads only a part of the HTML but don't the one I need to.

Here is my code:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://www.spaceweatherlive.com")

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil{
                print(error)
            }else{
//                let htmlcontent = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
                let htmlcontent = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))
//                let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "<h4 class=\"text-center\">Kp[0-9]</h4>", options: .caseInsensitive)
                let substring = "<h4 class=\"text-center\">Kp[0-9]"

                let matched = self.matches(for: substring, in: htmlcontent!)
                print(matched)
                if htmlcontent!.contains(substring){
                    print("Substring FOUND!!")
                }else{
//                    print("Nope, printing whole html:")
//                    print(htmlcontent)
                }
//                print(htmlcontent)


            }

        }
        task.resume()
```

Function to search for substring

```
func matches(for regex: String, in text: String) -> [String] {

    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex)
        let results = regex.matches(in: text,
                                    range: NSRange(text.startIndex..., in: text))
        return results.map {
            String(text[Range($0.range, in: text)!])
        }
    } catch let error {
        print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return []
    }
}
```

Thanks! any help or advice to try is very appreciated

This is the DIV which I need to retrieve (KP[0-9] value)

[image: Div which I'm trying to retrieve]

Answer (score 1):

We can maybe start with a simple expression and capture the SVG highchart part of the indicator that we have in the question:

```
(<div id="Kp_gauge".+?<\/div><\/div><\/div><\/div>)
```

Then, the title part can be written or attached to it with another similar expression.

Here, we are saying that start from:

```
<div id="Kp_gauge"
```

collect everything (`.+?`) to closest:

```
<\/div><\/div><\/div><\/div>
```

We can do the same for the title, if we wish, or we can just on the top of that write or add `Kp-index` and the problem may be solved.

The h3` title is always going to be:

```
<h3 class="card-header text-center">Kp-index <span class="text-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="The Kp-index is a geomagnetic activity index based on data from magnetometers around the world. The gauge below shows the most recently observed Kp-value from the Planetary K-index of the NOAA SWPC and can be used to make a rough estimate of the current global geomagnetic conditions."><svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-info-circle fa-w-16" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="info-circle" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M256 8C119.043 8 8 119.083 8 256c0 136.997 111.043 248 248 248s248-111.003 248-248C504 119.083 392.957 8 256 8zm0 110c23.196 0 42 18.804 42 42s-18.804 42-42 42-42-18.804-42-42 18.804-42 42-42zm56 254c0 6.627-5.373 12-12 12h-88c-6.627 0-12-5.373-12-12v-24c0-6.627 5.373-12 12-12h12v-64h-12c-6.627 0-12-5.373-12-12v-24c0-6.627 5.373-12 12-12h64c6.627 0 12 5.373 12 12v100h12c6.627 0 12 5.373 12 12v24z"></path></svg><!-- <i class="fas fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> --></span></h3>
```

which can be simply added.

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/AL7gJP/1/)

```js
const regex = /(<div id="Kp_gauge".+?<\/div><\/div><\/div><\/div>)/gm;
const str = `<div id="Kp_gauge" style="height: 170px; overflow: hidden;" data-highcharts-chart="6"><div id="highcharts-c5v532c-27" dir="ltr" class="highcharts-container " style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 448px; height: 170px; text-align: left; line-height: normal; z-index: 0; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"><svg version="1.1" class="highcharts-root" style="font-family:&quot;Lucida Grande&quot;, &quot;Lucida Sans Unicode&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="448" height="170" viewBox="0 0 448 170"><desc>Created with Highcharts 7.1.1</desc><defs><clipPath id="highcharts-c5v532c-28-"><rect x="0" y="0" width="428" height="145" fill="none"></rect></clipPath></defs><rect fill="none" class="highcharts-background" x="0" y="0" width="448" height="170" rx="0" ry="0"></rect><rect fill="none" class="highcharts-plot-background" x="10" y="10" width="428" height="145"></rect><g class="highcharts-pane-group" data-z-index="0"><path fill="#eee" d="M 108 140.5 A 116 116 0 0 1 339.9999420000048 140.38400001933334 L 293.5999652000029 140.4304000116 A 69.6 69.6 0 0 0 154.4 140.5 Z" class="highcharts-pane " stroke="#cccccc" stroke-width="1"></path></g><g class="highcharts-grid highcharts-yaxis-grid" data-z-index="1"><path fill="none" data-z-index="1" class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 224 140.5 L 108 140.5" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" data-z-index="1" class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 224 140.5 L 114.99565598883464 100.82566337422242" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" data-z-index="1" class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 224 140.5 L 135.13884459819855 65.93663727636142" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" data-z-index="1" class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 224 140.5 L 165.99999999999997 40.041053161005124" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" data-z-index="1" class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 224 140.5 L 203.8568113906361 26.262300650583867" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" data-z-index="1" class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 224 140.5 L 244.14318860936393 26.262300650583867" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" data-z-index="1" class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 224 140.5 L 282 40.04105316100511" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" data-z-index="1" class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 224 140.5 L 312.86115540180145 65.93663727636144" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" data-z-index="1" class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 224 140.5 L 333.00434401116536 100.82566337422242" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" data-z-index="1" class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 224 140.5 L 340 140.5" opacity="1"></path></g><rect fill="none" class="highcharts-plot-border" data-z-index="1" x="10" y="10" width="428" height="145"></rect><g class="highcharts-axis highcharts-yaxis" data-z-index="2"><path fill="none" class="highcharts-tick" stroke="#ccd6eb" stroke-width="2" d="M 108 140.5 L 118 140.5" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" class="highcharts-tick" stroke="#ccd6eb" stroke-width="2" d="M 114.99565598883464 100.82566337422242 L 124.39258219669372 104.24586480747911" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" class="highcharts-tick" stroke="#ccd6eb" stroke-width="2" d="M 135.13884459819855 65.93663727636142 L 142.79928902938835 72.36451337322681" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" class="highcharts-tick" stroke="#ccd6eb" stroke-width="2" d="M 165.99999999999997 40.041053161005124 L 170.99999999999997 48.701307198849506" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" class="highcharts-tick" stroke="#ccd6eb" stroke-width="2" d="M 203.8568113906361 26.262300650583867 L 205.59329316730538 36.11037818070595" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" class="highcharts-tick" stroke="#ccd6eb" stroke-width="2" d="M 244.14318860936393 26.262300650583867 L 242.40670683269462 36.11037818070595" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" class="highcharts-tick" stroke="#ccd6eb" stroke-width="2" d="M 282 40.04105316100511 L 277 48.70130719884949" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" class="highcharts-tick" stroke="#ccd6eb" stroke-width="2" d="M 312.86115540180145 65.93663727636144 L 305.2007109706117 72.36451337322683" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" class="highcharts-tick" stroke="#ccd6eb" stroke-width="2" d="M 333.00434401116536 100.82566337422242 L 323.60741780330625 104.24586480747911" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" class="highcharts-tick" stroke="#ccd6eb" stroke-width="2" d="M 340 140.5 L 330 140.5" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" class="highcharts-axis-line" data-z-index="7" d="M 108 140.5 A 116 116 0 0 1 339.9999420000048 140.38400001933334 M 224 140.5 A 0 0 0 0 0 224 140.5 "></path></g><g data-z-index="2" class="highcharts-data-labels highcharts-series-0 highcharts-solidgauge-series  highcharts-tracker" transform="translate(10,10) scale(1 1)"><g class="highcharts-label highcharts-data-label highcharts-data-label-color-0 highcharts-tracker" data-z-index="1" transform="translate(181,84)"></g></g><g class="highcharts-series-group" data-z-index="3"><g data-z-index="0.1" class="highcharts-series highcharts-series-0 highcharts-solidgauge-series  highcharts-tracker" transform="translate(10,10) scale(1 1)" clip-path="url(#highcharts-c5v532c-28-)"><path fill="rgb(85,191,59)" d="M 98 130.5 A 116 116 0 0 1 155.89957006990173 30.09910338080769 L 179.13974204194105 70.25946202848462 A 69.6 69.6 0 0 0 144.4 130.5 Z" sweep-flag="0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="highcharts-point highcharts-color-0"></path></g><g data-z-index="0.1" class="highcharts-markers highcharts-series-0 highcharts-solidgauge-series " transform="translate(10,10) scale(1 1)" clip-path="none"></g></g><text x="10" class="highcharts-title" data-z-index="4" style="color:#333333;font-size:18px;fill:#333333;" y="24"></text><text x="224" text-anchor="middle" class="highcharts-subtitle" data-z-index="4" style="color:#666666;fill:#666666;" y="24"></text><g class="highcharts-legend" data-z-index="7"><rect fill="none" class="highcharts-legend-box" rx="0" ry="0" x="0" y="0" width="8" height="8" visibility="hidden"></rect><g data-z-index="1"><g></g></g></g><g class="highcharts-axis-labels highcharts-yaxis-labels" data-z-index="7"><text x="98" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="144.49999999999997" opacity="1">0</text><text x="105.59872978097555" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="101.40546194096572" opacity="1">1</text><text x="127.47840016700879" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="63.50876117949602" opacity="1">2</text><text x="160.99999999999997" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="35.38079912316074" opacity="1">3</text><text x="202.1203296139668" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="20.414223120461784" opacity="1">4</text><text x="245.87967038603324" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="20.414223120461784" opacity="1">5</text><text x="287" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="35.38079912316073" opacity="1">6</text><text x="320.5215998329912" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="63.508761179496034" opacity="1">7</text><text x="342.40127021902447" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="101.40546194096574" opacity="1">8</text><text x="350" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="144.5" opacity="1">9</text></g></svg><div class="highcharts-loading highcharts-loading-hidden" style="position: absolute; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); opacity: 0; text-align: center; z-index: 10; left: 10px; top: 10px; width: 428px; height: 145px; display: none;"><span class="highcharts-loading-inner" style="font-weight: bold; position: relative; top: 45%;">Loading…</span></div><div class="highcharts-data-labels highcharts-series-0 highcharts-solidgauge-series  highcharts-tracker" style="position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 10px; opacity: 1; visibility: inherit;"><div class="highcharts-label highcharts-data-label highcharts-data-label-color-0 highcharts-tracker" style="position: absolute; left: 181px; top: 84px; opacity: 1;"><span data-z-index="1" style="position: absolute; font-family: &quot;Lucida Grande&quot;, &quot;Lucida Sans Unicode&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; white-space: nowrap; font-weight: bold; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; left: 5px; top: 5px;"><h4 class="text-center">Kp3</h4><div class="text-center" style="font-size:10px;color:silver">18-21 UTC</div></span></div></div></div></div>`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

---

#### Edit

For getting the `Kp` we can simply use an expression similar to:

```
<h[1-6] class="text-center">(Kp[0-9]+)<\/h[1-6]>
```

```js
const regex = /<h[1-6] class="text-center">(Kp[0-9]+)<\/h[1-6]>/gm;
const str = `<span data-z-index="1" style="position: absolute; font-family: &quot;Lucida Grande&quot;, &quot;Lucida Sans Unicode&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; white-space: nowrap; font-weight: bold; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; left: 5px; top: 5px;"><h4 class="text-center">Kp3</h4><div class="text-center" style="font-size:10px;color:silver">18-21 UTC</div></span>`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/f3pWXJ/1/)

Comment: That is a nice idea, but especially in this case we need to retrieve current gadget value to store it into a variable and do stuff with it in swift,  which is located in the div of the regex, and that's why <h4 class=\"text-center\">Kp[0-9]  Regex value to locate only the "KPnumber" value

Comment: Yes! That is right! 
could it be possible you get an H3 because of screen resolution? 
as you can see in the screenshot, I got an H4

Comment: Well, it works and got the h4 with the current value in code snippet!
Is it swift 4? I just can't wait to try!

Comment: Well, that is the main problem here... WKWebView loads the HTML doc without or before javascript execution, so the gauge div is never there